# SQL Query Total Requests in the Last 8 weeks breakdown

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working on a query that shows a breakdown of the number of open support requests within the last 8 weeks, broken down by week. I found a couple of answers on SO and have changed things to meet my needs.

The query I have takes the data and pivots it to show the breakdown. However, I am getting an error about the createdDate not being in the aggregate function and I'm not sure where I need to put that in.

Example:

```
Declare @DatePeriod DATETIME = GETUTCDATE()

Select  IsNull([1],0) as 'Week 1',
        IsNull([2],0) as 'Week 2',
        IsNull([3],0) as 'Week 3',
        IsNull([4],0) as 'Week 4',
        IsNull([5],0) as 'Week 5',
        IsNull([6],0) as 'Week 6',
        IsNull([7],0) as 'Week 7',
        IsNull([8],0) as 'Week 8'
From 
(
Select  
        DATEDIFF(week, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, createdDate), 0), createdDate) +1 as [Weeks],
        COUNT(reqID) as 'TotalOpened'

From support_tickets
Where DatePart(Month, createdDate)= DatePart(Month, @DatePeriod)
AND tool = 244
)p 
Pivot (COUNT(TotalOpened) for Weeks in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8])) as pv
```

Can anyone point out where I would need to add the grouping if I am also pivoting the data?

```
Column 'support_tickets.createdDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(week, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, createdDate), 0), createdDate) +1
```

right after:

```
AND tool = 244
```